# how to sortOn cell color on ExcelScript for web?

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I am trying to sort in descending order the cells with a 'rose' background, as you can do in the 'filter' or 'custom sort' but with ExcelScript for web:

```
 range.getSort().apply([ {
    ascending: false,
    key: 5,
    sortOn: ExcelScript.SortOn.cellColor,
    subField: "rose"
 }]);
```

But it does not sort.  I am pretty sure I am misusing the `subField` field, but the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.sortfield?view=office-scripts) are not very helpful.  If I just sort in ascending or descending order, it works:

```
 range.getSort().apply([ {
    ascending: true,
    key: 5
 }]);
```

How can I use properly the `sortOn` feature to sort by cellColor, or other property?

Comment: This is interesting. I was able to sort by color in Excel Online using Custom Sort. I tried to record the sorting using the Record Actions button on the Automate tab. However, it doesn't look like any color specific action was recorded in the script.

Comment: I did the same on different places and it just does **not** appear....  It also does not work with Font...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `subField`, have you tried specifying the `color`?

This seems to be working for me:

```js
range.getSort().apply([{
    key: 1,
    ascending: true,
    sortOn: ExcelScript.SortOn.cellColor,
    color: "yellow"
}]);
```

Although it seems to be a bug that the recorder doesn't generate `sortOn` and `color` for the `sortField`.